# inserting a token while parsing a file - bash

Tags: bash

I have a file with this structure:

```
ma${token}jid-azimi-865131021
javad-ya${token}rip-865132012
```

and here is my program:

```
IFS="-"

token="12345678"

cat input.txt | while read col1 col2 col3; do
    echo ${col1}
    echo ${col2}
    echo ${col3}
    echo "********************************"
done
```

I want to insert `${token}` while reading file. because token is a dynamic word and I can not change it inside the file every time. So I add `${token}` to the file once. But the output of program is:

```
ma${token}jid
azimi
865131021
********************************
javad
ya${token}rip
865132012
********************************
```

Why this is happening? `ma${token}jid` should be expand like this: `echo ma${token}jid`, then `12345678` should be inserted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value of `col1` is the 13-character string `ma${token}jid`. When you write `echo ${col1}` with no quotes, the shell replaces `${col1}` by the value of the variable, then performs word splitting (i.e. breaking up the value into separate words at `$IFS` characters) and filename generation (i.e. globbing). Variable values are not recursively expanded using shell syntax. If you use double quotes around variable substitution (which you should do unless you have a good reason not to), `"$col1"` straightforwardly expands to the value of `col1`.

If your strings are tame enough (i.e. contain no shell special characters, apart from the `${token}` that you want to substitute), then you can construct a string from `$col1` that you evaluate as a shell snippet. In your example, the following line would print `ma12345678jid`:

```
eval "echo $col1"
```

Alternatively, replace the marker `${token}` by the desired value. You can do it with a string substitution in bash:

```
while read -r col1 col2 col3; do
    echo "${col1//'${token}'/$token}"
    echo "${col2}"
    echo "${col3}"
    echo "********************************"
done <input.txt
```

You can also do it with `awk`, as a pre- or post-processing step (depending on whether you want to perform the replacement in other columns as well).

```
<input.txt awk -v repl="$token" '{gsub(/\${token}/, repl); print}' |
while read …
```

You can perform the replacement with `sed`, but only if you're sure that none of the characters `&\/` and newline appear in the replacement text `$token` (you can change the separator character from `/` to something else if there's another character which you're sure doesn't appear in `$token`).

```
<input.txt sed -e "s/\\\${token}/$token/" |
while read …
```

Answer (score 3):

Variables when echoed are not subject to variable expansion. Prepend `eval` to `echo`. This might work for simple cases, but can break if your strings contain `|` or quotes. Or, just do the substitution:

```
echo ${col1/'${token}'/$token}
```